# How does C++ handle vectors when passing from a function to main?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, cout

I'm seeing strange behaviour in the output of a 'simple' function that generates the binary representation of an integer. I aim to use the function in another code, but first want to see it working by printing to the console. I first define the function dec2bin to take a number and the length of the required bitstring. After defining a vector that will be returned by the function, the vector is populated with the required binary values. In the main function, the vector is accessed and printed element-wise to the console. However, the output is incorrect unless I include an arbitrary cout statement within the vector populating for loop.

The function is defined as follows:

```
vector<int> dec2bin(int N, int j){
    vector<int> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(N);
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int r = j >> i;
        if (r & 1)
            myvec[N-i-1] = 1;
        else 
            myvec[N-i-1] = 0;
        //cout << " ";
    }
    return myvec;
}
```

My main function is:

```
int main(){
    int length = 8;
    int num = 15;
    vector<int> myvec = dec2bin(length,num);
    for (int j=0; j<length; j++){cout << myvec[j];}
    return 0;
}
```

When the commented out line (cout << " ") is included within the for loop the output is correct, with 00001111. Without that line (or with the line outside of the for loop) the output is incorrectly 00001141130.

I have read various things about pointers and memory allocation, so expect this is where I am going wrong; however, I can't quite see how to incorporate those ideas into my own code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: *"the output is incorrect unless I include an arbitrary cout statement"* - This is a great indicator that you have Undefined Behavior somewhere.

Comment: `myvec.push_back(N);` does _not_ push `N` items, but the number `N`. After this your vector contains _exactly one_ element. You may be looking for `myvec.resize(N)`.

Comment: Many thanks for both answers. The correction from @churill has done the trick. I see now the mistake in using push_back and will go back to the textbooks! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
myvec[N-i-1] = 1;
```

You are invoking undefined behavior for any index other than `0`.

`myvec.push_back(N);` pushes a single element to the vector, and you never add more elements to the vector. When you access a vector out of bounds, you will not get a compiler error or runtime exception, but your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which means the output could be literally anything.

Actually, it seems like you just confused `push_back()` with `resize()`. And instead of `resize()`, you can pass the size to the constructor. If you replace:

```
vector<int> myvec;
myvec.push_back(N);
```

with:

```
std::vector<int> myvec(N);
```

or:

```
std::vector<int> myvec;
myvec.resize(N);
```

You get a vector with `N` elements, and accessing `myvec[i]` is fine for any index `0 <= i < N`. Alternatively, you could call `myvec.reserve(10)` to let the vector allocate space for `N` elements. The vector will then still be empty, and you have to `push_back()` any element you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the unallocated memory because you only pushed back(`push_back()`) once and due to it you are getting undefined behaviour.
You should use `.at()` function instead of `[]` operator for accessing the vector element, it'll throw the exception out of bounds.

You need to use `push_back()` for insertion into the vector or you can use `vector.resize(size)` during vector declaration then it'll save you from undefined behavior.

Thanx

Comment: `vector.reserve` does not change the size of the vector. Did you mean `resize` ?

Comment: Nope, I meant he can reserve N size during declaration of the vector required and can insert accordingly, thus avoiding undefined behavior.

Comment: but after `vector.reserve(size)` it is still ub `vector[1]` because the size is still 0

Comment: My bad got confused with `resize()` and `reserve()`. Thanx